# div stacks images vertically

Tags: html, css, position

I was making an image gallery using possition:inherit; which put each image one after the other. this was working fine until i had to add a div to each image. Which then caused all the images to stack like this [this is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMamx.png)

I tried adding position:inherit; to all of the div s but it didn’t fix the issue. and there is no other way of doing that I have to do without the divs.

Any Help would be Appreciated.

```html
<div>
<div>
<a href="http://google.com"><img BORDER="0" SRC="files/1.jpg" style="width:304px;height:228px; position:inherit;" ></a>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div>
<a href="http://google.com"><img BORDER="0" SRC="files/1.jpg" style="width:304px;height:228px; position:inherit;" ></a>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div>
<a href="http://google.com"><img BORDER="0" SRC="files/1.jpg" style="width:304px;height:228px; position:inherit;" ></a>
</div>
</div>
```

i also have this hover function which i need the text to apear underneath the image when the image gets hovered on. using`div{float: left;}` it makes the text come to the right of the image.

```css
#main {




}

a {
    color: blue;
    position:inherit;
}

#hidden {
    display:none;
    color: orange;


 }

#main:hover #hidden {
    display:block;

    
    
    
}

div{float: left;}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<a href="http://google.com"><img BORDER="0" SRC="files/1.jpg" style="width:304px;height:228px; " ></a>
<div id="hidden">
<p>hi how are you</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to your edit, just put the text (`<p/>`) inside the div and make sure the image element inside the div is `float:none;`

EDIT: Don't make all your div's floating by using `div{float:left;}`
RATHER: do `#img_div_id{float:left}` (unless you want every div on the whole page to float left of coure :) )

Comment: if it is just float left, dont assign an id, you might want to use it again. Just use a class: `.pull-left{ float: left; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can make images in one line using `float: left;`

```css
div{float: left;}
```

```html
<div>
<div>
<a href="http://google.com"><img BORDER="0" SRC="files/1.jpg" style="width:200px;height:200px; position:inherit;" ></a>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div>
<a href="http://google.com"><img BORDER="0" SRC="files/1.jpg" style="width:200px;height:200px; position:inherit;" ></a>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div>
<a href="http://google.com"><img BORDER="0" SRC="files/1.jpg" style="width:200px;height:200px; position:inherit;" ></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank i have a problem with this. i updated my questin acordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One More Example:

```
div
{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO UPDATED**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/7749besp/1/)

Comment: i dont want them to line up veticly. i have also updated my questin.